# Kdocker doesn't appear in notification area in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bug-reporting

Running `kdocker` and then clicking on a window hides the window, but no icon appears in the notification area in Ubuntu 14.04 in either Gnome Flashback (Metacity) or Xfce-session.
If I find kdocker's process ID and kill it, I get the hidden window back.

This looks like a bug. It worked fine in Ubuntu 13.10 and earlier.

Comment: If you think it is a bug, report is on http://launchpad.net.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

It worked for all of my notification area icons.

Comment: Nope, `libappindicator1` is already installed.

The problem might be `kdocker`-specific. For example the Opera browser puts its icon in the notification area like always.